# Paypal Completed Transaction Cookie on client - Need to expire as Leaves Shopping Cart Filled

Tags: php

Been reading posts and testing solutions for days.....
Basically, when 'Add to Cart' button clicked, Paypal creates 3 cookies on client. When Checkout completed, another 3 cookies created on client. All appears fine until user views Paypal basket and contents previously purchased are still there due to info being passed back to Paypal via active cookie. Need to expire this active cookie when checkout completed. BUT....cannot get Paypal to pass the cookie name to my web site (name on setcookie function is mandatory), many posts say you cannot modify another web sites cookies placed on client, but you can clear them manually ??? using a cleaner or delete manually through browser. Using the 'custom' variable on Paypal PDT appears to be only for passing through your data from you to Paypal and back again.

What am I missing here - this must be a common problem for anyone using the Paypal shopping cart. No response from Paypal support. Is there any other link between transaction id's and these Paypal cookies? obviously I only only want to expire the cookies created for my clients transactions, not any other Paypal transactions my user would have made through other sites. Another post says you cannot view cookies until page is reloaded, but the Paypal cookies are already set before my transaction completion page is loaded. Would be great if the cookie names created for my session could be loaded to an array which I could read back and expire them, but using $_COOKIE always returns blank.

HELP - Can you get Paypal to pass the name of the final transaction cookie?
How can you identify the cookies without knowing the names (obviously you cannot read a clients cookies, strictly prohibited).
Not using a session in my PHP pages - should I and how would you use this to expire cookies created by Paypal as Paypal uses it's own session number.

running out of hair to pull out. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: you cant, thankfully, do anything to the paypal cookies. i don't understand the need to, or the approach here. If there 'limited' cart functions are not working for you, i would suggest installing a full service shopping-cart solution

Comment: Thanks for that info, I wont continue to find a method of expiring the cookies. I would have thought that a logical end to the process would be that Paypal would sort out the cookies on the client when a 'Success' message was received back to them via IPN, but I suppose thats asking too much. Ok, the carts will empty after 21 days, so I will just have to look out for multiple purchases of the same item (all my items are unique), and go back to finishing the code for my own custom basket processing. At least that way I have control over items purchased and will only use Paypal for total payment

Comment: there are numerous shopping carts valuable that do all the hard work for you .